# Addition of a Disturbance to a Microgrid system

Tags: microgrid

I have a microgrid system which is represented in state space model by 
\$\dot{\mathbf{x}}= Ax \$. The dimension of \$A\$  is \$32\times32\$ . I want to introduce a step disturbance in one of the states and plot the resulting response of some states  in MATLAB/SIMULINK. What will be the change in the state space representation when a disturbance in one of the state is introduced. How will I get the response of some states with time as the step input is introduced ?

Comment: Do you mean how do you implement a Kalman filter in Matlab? or how does one convert dynamic system model from/to state-space form?

Comment: Not a Kalman filter. I simply want to know what will be the change in state space representation matrices(A,B,C,D) if I introduce a step disturbance in one of the states. How will I get the plot of variation  in some other state if a step disturbance in one of the state is introduced ?